# how to make custom list classification in tensorflow with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

how to make custom list classification in tensorflow with python 3?

I was trying to make a custom dataset with this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
# make the custom dataset
dataset_data = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]], [[3, 2, 1], [5, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]]
dataset_label = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
dataset_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataset_data, dataset_label))
```

after that, I was try to make the model with this code

```
# make model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

after that, I was try to compile the model with this code

```
# compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

after that, I was try to train the model with this code

```
# fit model
model.fit(dataset_tf, epochs=10)
```

after that, I was try to predict the data with this code

```
# predict
predict_data = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
prediction = model.predict(predict_data)
print(prediction)
```

after that, I got an error message like this

> ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node
> strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32,
> begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0,
> shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1,
> strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with
> computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] =
> <1>.

what should I do? and why do I get this error?

my environment

- Tensorflow version 2.8.0
- Python version 3.7

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to encode your target string label to integer labels. And may need to add a batch axis to the training pairs. Try the following code.

```
dataset_data = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
                [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 
                [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]], 
                [[3, 2, 1], [5, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]]
                
# dataset_label = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C']
dataset_label = [0, 1, 2, 3] # decode later

dataset_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataset_data, dataset_label))
# add batch axis
dataset_tf = dataset_tf.map(lambda x, y: (x[None, ...], y[None, ...]) )
dataset_tf.element_spec
(TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=tf.int32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# input shape (None, 3, 3)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(3,3))) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

model.fit(dataset_tf, epochs=1) # OK
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 3.1034
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f0c7ac0db10>
```

```
predict_data = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
prediction = model.predict(predict_data[None, ...])
print(prediction) # OK
[[0.47527248]]
```

Comment: That's work, but how to get input_shape automatically? So whatever the data are given can work well for the program.

Comment: Input shape from model or dataloader?

Comment: Both, I used this code to find the dataset shape automatically, but it's too long. Can you help me find the shortest way?
`code`
dataset_data = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
                [[5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4]], 
                [[3, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]], 
                [[5, 4, 3], [5, 4, 3]], 
                [[3, 2, 1], [5, 2, 1]]]
datasetShape = np.shape(dataset_data)
datasetShape = list(datasetShape)
datasetShape.pop(0)
datasetShape = tuple(datasetShape)
print(datasetShape)
`code`

Comment: the purpose of dataset shape is used in this code
dataset_tf.element_spec(TensorSpec(shape=(1, 3, 3), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
and
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(3,3)))